# Sharepoint CAML Query IN operator

Tags: caml

I have a sharepoint list with managed metadata column and I have to find items matching values from columns.
If I filter the list for a column, let's say COLUMN1

```
<In>
        <FieldRef LookupId='TRUE' ID='919cad04-5872-42a5-8c79-93e38e5e5b96' />
        <Values>
          <Value Type='Integer'>65</Value>
        </Values>
      </In>
```

It returns the record RECORD1. 
Now i filter the list for a second column, let's say COLUMNB,

```
<In>
        <FieldRef LookupId='TRUE' ID='5a6a5ee4-d125-4c99-9109-f943d8da7af0' />
        <Values>
          <Value Type='Integer'>68</Value>
        </Values>
      </In>
```

It returns record RECORD2.
The issue is that if I run the query

```
<Or>
        <In>
          <FieldRef LookupId='TRUE' ID='5a6a5ee4-d125-4c99-9109-f943d8da7af0' />
          <Values>
            <Value Type='Integer'>68</Value>
          </Values>
        </In>
        <In>
          <FieldRef LookupId='TRUE' ID='919cad04-5872-42a5-8c79-93e38e5e5b96' />
          <Values>
            <Value Type='Integer'>65</Value>
          </Values>
        </In>
      </Or>
```

No record is returned. I was expecting both record RECORD1 and RECORD2.
BTW SharePoint version is 2010.

Any help is appreciated

Comment: Instead of In why you are not using `Eq`?

Comment: What type is your fields? Is it Lookups or Integer columns?

Comment: Columns are taxoniny fields and the query is built @ runtime and I don't know the number of values the user wnats to query

Comment: Can you just use the internal name of column instead of using lookup like: `<FieldRef Name='COLUMN1' />`

Comment: Hi Yousuf, I really don't think the FieldRef is causing the issue I'm talking about. The issue is that if I use the In operator inside a boolean Or it doesn't work as expected :-(

Answer (score 4, accepted):

maybe a bug on FieldRef using ID or LookupId because of querying the list in this way

```
<Where>
<Or>
<In>
        <FieldRef Name="COLUMN1"/>
        <Values>
          <Value Type='Text'>VALUE1</Value>
          <Value Type='Text'>VALUE2</Value>
        </Values>
      </In>
<In>
        <FieldRef Name="COLUMN2"/>
        <Values>
          <Value Type='Text'>VALUE3</Value>
          <Value Type='Text'>VALUE4</Value>
        </Values>
      </In>
</Or>
</Where>
```

returns the expected results.
Thanks to all.

Comment: This is what I had mentioned in the comment.

Comment: Correct Nadeem but it souns really strange. Thanks a lot

Answer (score -1):

in CAML `<IN>` operator should be used as follows

```
<In>
  <FieldRef LookupId='TRUE' ID='5a6a5ee4-d125-4c99-9109-f943d8da7af0' />
  <Values>
     <Value Type='Integer'>68</Value>
     <Value Type='Integer'>65</Value>
  </Values>
</In>
```

Let mw know if you have any questions.

Comment: @Gianluca wants to filter on different columns.