# Caml query to filter by two columns of a sharepoint

Tags: sharepoint-online, caml-query

Below CAML query is working for filtering the list items with one column, I have tried to add another column to filter it but facing some errors.

`"<View Scope='RecursiveAll'><Query><Where><In><FieldRef Name="OID" /><Values><Value Type="Text">749</Value><Value Type="Text">748</Value><Value Type="Text">598</Value><Value Type="Text">106</Value></Values></In></Where></Query></View>"`

I want to filter it again with one more column with some values.

Answer (score 1):

**[This question is duplicated with the following one]**

Here is your answer,

[Sharepoint CAML Query IN operator](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/144577/sharepoint-caml-query-in-operator)

Answer (score 1):

This should work

```
<Where>
<And>
    <In>
        <FieldRef Name="OID" />
        <Values>
            <Value Type='Text'>1</Value>
            <Value Type='Text'>2</Value>
        </Values>

    </In>

    <In>
        <FieldRef Name="SecField" />
        <Values>
            <Value Type='Text'>3</Value>
            <Value Type='Text'>4</Value>
        </Values>
    </In>
</And></Where>
```

Comment: I think you have an extra set of AND tags in there....